# Convert two Timestamps to Datetime and get their difference in Python

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime, time

```
import datetime
start = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1485008513.00000))
end = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1485788517.80000))

#Duration
duration = end - start
```

My result is :

```
9 days, 0:40:04.800000
```

But it must be like this (without days, only hours, minutes and seconds) :

```
216:40:04.800000
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but works (for your example, durations less then a day and much more then 1000 days) - but its ugly:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1485788515.0000))
end = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(1485788517.80000))

#Duration
duration = end - start

dur = str(duration).split(',')
print dur

# less then a day is not str() as 0days, ... so we fix that here by introducing artificial
# zero day if a split only retunrs 1 element 
if len(dur) < 2:
    d = ["0", dur[0]]
    dur = d

dayHours = int(dur[0].replace('days',''))*24  # remove the days, mult with 24
hours = dur[1].split(':')[0]                  # get the partial hours of this part
minsSecs = ':'.join(dur[1].split(':')[1:])    # split+join the rest from the hours

# print all combined 
print (str( dayHours+ int(hours) ) + ':' + minsSecs)
```

Output:

```
216:40:04.800000
```

---

Maybe better:

```
totSec = duration.total_seconds()    

hours = totSec // (60*60) 
mins = (totSec - (hours*60*60)) // 60
secs = totSec -  (hours*60*60) - mins * 60 

print "{:2}:{:2}:{:09.6f}".format(int(hours),int(mins),secs)
```